# How do I tell that which part of findOne will get Executed in OR Query NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this code Syntax.

```
ChatSchema.findOne({person1Id: person1Id, person2Id: person2Id} || {person1Id: person2Id, person2Id: person1Id},
```

If The condition within first curly braces matches the requirement then I want to set the flag. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read Docs.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) $or operator is helpful for you

```
ChatSchema.fineOne({
    $or: [
        {person1Id: person1Id, person2Id: person2Id},
        {person1Id: person2Id, person2Id: person1Id}
    ]
});
```

---

I read your question totally wrong , sorry ;)

If It was SQL, transaction would be capable way. but mongodb, I recommend querying twice. It is most simple and obvious.

Comment: That Helped !! Used or you mentioned and queried twice. :)